# Visibility change with css not working

Tags: css

Trying to change the visibility of my form on click of the button, however the visibility of the form doesnt change on click.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I've looked at other code and they are doing the same thing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
        To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
        To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
        and open the template in the editor.
     -->
     <html>
         <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <style type="text/css">
                #cardInput{
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom:400px;
                    right:700px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
            <!--this is the form itself i used a div to contain  it-->
                <div id="cardInput">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Name:</td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Font Size:</td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="font" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">Colour:</td>
                            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="colour" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"></td>
                            <td align="left"><button type="button" onclick="makeCard()">Make Your Card</button></td>
        <!--on submit i want it to run the function that hides the form-->
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script>
                function makeCard(){
                    //this is the line that isnt working 
                    document.getElementsByTagName("form").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
             </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Sorry about the poor formating of code I rarely use this.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` as the name suggests (plural) returns a list of nodes (multiple as in an array), so you must use it as `document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";` for the line to work. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6Urw/)

Comment: Nice to know it helped mate. One additional note, as you probably already guessed the `[0]` is the array index. So if you have multiple form elements, you must modify that number to target the required element (or) have a loop if you want to affect all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")
```

always returns array of form tags found in page. so you should use it like

```
function makeCard(){
 document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
                   }
```

see demo http://jsfiddle.net/t2YLa/

Answer (score 0):

> Add id in form id = "form" inside the tag and call in javascript like this :
>   document.getElementById("form").style.visibility = "hidden";